# Event handler for dynamically created checkboxes doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I want to use my own event handler for all five checkboxes.
I create one checkbox in the code and then clone it four times.

My problems with this code: I can check and uncheck the first checkbox (the checkbox in the code).
But the first checkbox doesn't use my event handler but its own (I set a breakpoint in my
"$('input:checkbox').live('click', function (event) {..." code and it is never reached if I click the first checkbox.
The four other boxes reach my event handler but all four get checked if I click only at one.
And I can only check the four boxes if the first box (the one in the code) is checked and I can only uncheck them if the first box is unchecked. There seems to be a lot of side effects I don't understand.
This is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<title>My Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onfocus="readvalues()">
<div id="mypage" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input:checkbox').live('click', function (event) {       
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
         $(this).prop('checked', false);
         //$(this).removeAttr('checked');
         $(this).checkboxradio("refresh");
         //$(this).attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
     } else {
         $(this).prop('checked', true);    
         //$(this).attr('checked', true);
         $(this).checkboxradio("refresh");
     }
     //$(this).prop('checked', true);    
     //$(this).attr('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
     $(this).checkboxradio("refresh");
     //$(selector).trigger('create');    
   });
});    
</script>

  <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="fieldcontainid">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="fieldsetid">
       <div id="sample">
       <input id="checkboxsample" class="custom" type="checkbox" data-iconpos="left" name="checkboxsample">
       <label id="labelsample" for="checkboxsample">Test</label>
       </div>
       <div id="existing"></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
<script>
readvalues = function()
{

    var existing = document.getElementById('existing');
    existing.textContent = '';

    for (i=0; i<=3; i++)  
    {  
        var clonecheckbox = $("#sample").clone(false);
        $("#existing").append(clonecheckbox);
        clonecheckbox.attr("id",i.toString());
        $("#"+i.toString()).children().children().eq(0).attr("id","cb"+i.toString());
        $("#"+i.toString()).children().children().eq(0).attr("name","cb"+i.toString());

        $("#"+i.toString()).children().children().eq(1).attr("id","label"+i.toString());
        $("#"+i.toString()).children().children().eq(1).attr("for","cb"+i.toString());
    }
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What changes have I to do in my code to use my own event handler four all five checkboxes?
Is my event handling to check/uncheck checkboxes correct?

Answer (score 0):

`live` method and `:checkbox` selector are deprecated, try using the `on` method, also note that when you clone the inputs you should change their `IDs` before appending them, having on ID for several elements makes your markup invalid, one solution is using classes instead of the IDs.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to a function and bind it to the original:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input:checkbox').on('click', doTheWork);
}); 

function doTheWork(event)   {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
             $(this).prop('checked', false);
             //$(this).removeAttr('checked');
             $(this).checkboxradio("refresh");
             //$(this).attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
         } else {
             $(this).prop('checked', true);    
             //$(this).attr('checked', true);
             $(this).checkboxradio("refresh");
         }
         //$(this).prop('checked', true);    
         //$(this).attr('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
         $(this).checkboxradio("refresh");
         //$(selector).trigger('create');    
       }
```

Then when you create the checkbox just do this:

```
clonecheckbox.click(doTheWork);
```

Comment: I did the changes.I had also another change to do:I bind the click event in my for loop to the input field instead to the div: $("#"+i.toString()).children().children().eq(0).click(doTheWork); otherwise I get the div field for "this" in the doTheWork function. For the first checkbox (the in the html code) the function doTheWork is called for every click. But for the other checkboxes doTheWork is only called for every second click. And the checkboxes get never checked. $(this).prop('checked') is always true in the if order although the checkboxes aren't checked. What's wrong?